# Running classes to make excel report for multiple items out of array and loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have most of the foundation here to take a hardcoded array, run a sql command for each id in the array in a loop, and then create data for each that would eventually come out as an excel report for each array record.

So I'll be calling `makeReportFile.php` which will in turn call on `testReports.php`. At this point, I want to loop on the array so that the key/number is plugged into my sql query and the name of the array element is used afterwards for filenames and email subjects, if that makes sense.

What I'm looking for once this runs is for one folder called 'excel/Reports' that would have 12 excel reports named 'First Address.xlsx', 'Second Address.xlsx', etc. My issue here is that I can easily run this separately with each as its own file but I want to run it this way so that if I add or remove elements from the array I just change one area of code.

How can I properly complete and loop here in order to achieve what I'm looking for?

testReports.php

```
class testReports  {

    static function getData(){

        $items = array(
        1452 => 'First Address',
        1462 => 'Second Address',
        1432 => 'Third Address',
        1352 => 'Fourth Address',
        1152 => 'Fifth Address',
        1682 => 'Sixth Address',
        1982 => 'Sevent Address',
        1342 => 'Eighth Address',
        1902 => 'Ninth Address',
        1572 => 'Tenth Address',
        1252 => 'Eleventh Address',
        1842 => 'Twelvth Address',
        );

        $sql = "
            select *
            from tableTwo
            where number = ?          
        ";

        //This should search by 1452,1462,1432, and so on

        foreach($item in $items){
            $results = DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql);
        }

        return $results;
    }

    public static function makeName(){
        $currentTime = time();
        return $name . "Report";
    }

    //This should return "First Address Report", "Second Address Report" and so on
}
```

makeReportFile.php

```
class makeReportFile
{

    public function handle() {
        $data = testingReports::getData();
        $filename = testingReports::makeName();
        $filepath = 'excel/reports';    
        $fileWriter->store('xlsx', storage_path($filepath));


        $body = "Attached is the" . $name . "report";
        Mail::raw($body , function ($message) use ($emails,$filepath,$filename) {

            $message->subject($name . "Report");
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Now that I look at it, the array would probably need to be in the first class/file and loop around each, then pass the array values into the methods for the next class file